# Traveling on a TN visa after having an approved I-140

Tags: immigration, greencard, canadian-citizens, tn-visa

I am just wondering if it's risky to travel on a TN visa after having an approved I-140 (including traveling from and to the US for sake of renewal the TN visa itself). My employer wants to sponsor an EB2 visa for me, but since I am a China-born Canadian citizen, I understand that the priority date is quite backlogged for I-485 filing. If the I-140 were approved, this will likely mean I will need to spend years waiting to file I-485.

I am worried that having an I-140 alone will cause difficulties for traveling, in particular for admission back to the US on the TN visa, as the visa holder is not supposed to show immigration intent. I have heard conflicting opnions on this:

1. Some argue that I-140 alone does not constitute immigration intent based on [this memo](https://chicagoimmigrationattorney.net/images/stories/tn-nafta-applicant-may-file-140.pdf), so one need not worry about the TN visa being invalidated.
2. However, there are also arguments saying that filing an I-140 creates a presumption for immigration, hence invalidating the TN visa.

Both arguments are sound to me, and the law firms I've consulted with seem to be biased towards the first one. So I'm quite confused, and wanted to hear your guys' opnions on this. Any comment / reference of resources is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The memo seems to clearly indicate the USCIS position. I don't think you'll get any better opinions here, rather potential anecdotal evidence that wouldn't mean much.